# Unable to Publish PowerShell Module to Local Repo that is Dependent on an Externally Managed Module

Tags: powershell, repository

I've written and compiled a PowerShell module that is essentially a glorified wrapper of the ActiveDirectory module. My module has a proper Module Manifest file as well. I've also created a PSRepository that is hosted on a server and that is where I'd like to host this module of mine.

When I run the following command:

```
Publish-Module -Name ADWrap -Repository MyRepo -Tags ActiveDirectory -Force -Verbose
```

I get this error:

> Publish-PSArtifactUtility : PowerShellGet cannot resolve the module dependency 'ActiveDirectory' of the module 'ADWrap' on the repository 'MyRepo'. Verify that the 
>   dependent module 'ActiveDirectory' is available in the repository 'MyRepo'. If this dependent module 'ActiveDirectory' is managed externally, add it to the 
>   ExternalModuleDependencies entry in the PSData section of the module manifest.
>   At C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules\PowerShellGet\1.0.0.1\PSModule.psm1:1227 char:17
>   +                 Publish-PSArtifactUtility -PSModuleInfo $moduleInfo `
>   +                 ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Publish-PSArtifactUtility], InvalidOperationException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : UnableToResolveModuleDependency,Publish-PSArtifactUtility

There is not a lot of info on the ExternalModuleDependencies entry. I sought Google out and found these sites that helped a bit [here](https://github.com/OneGet/oneget/issues/164)

After generating the Module Manifest I did the following to update the properties of it:

```
Update-ModuleManifest -Path "\\Server\PowerShell Modules\ADWrap\Version 1.6.1\ADWrap\ADWrap.psd1" -ExternalModuleDependencies 'ActiveDirectory'
```

That gave me what looks like the proper way to include the ExternalModuleDepencies code but I still get the error. The PrivateData code is the module manifest looks like this:

```
# Private data to pass to the module specified in RootModule/ModuleToProcess. This may also contain a PSData hashtable with additional module metadata used by PowerShell.
PrivateData = @{

    PSData = @{

        # Tags applied to this module. These help with module discovery in online galleries.
        # Tags = @()

        # A URL to the license for this module.
        # LicenseUri = ''

        # A URL to the main website for this project.
        # ProjectUri = ''

        # A URL to an icon representing this module.
        # IconUri = ''

        # ReleaseNotes of this module
        # ReleaseNotes = ''

        # External dependent modules of this module
        ExternalModuleDependencies = 'ActiveDirectory'

    } # End of PSData hashtable

 } # End of PrivateData hashtable
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing and I haven't seen a lot about this kind of issue online so any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I found something interesting. [This answer on PowerShell.org](https://powershell.org/forums/topic/externalmoduledependencies-requiredmodules/) indicated that the ExternalModuleDependencies property (that I generated through the Update-ModuleManifest cmdlet) was actually generated incorrectly.

I manually opened the updated module manifest and changed this:

```
    # External dependent modules of this module
    ExternalModuleDependencies = 'ActiveDirectory'
```

to this:

```
    # External dependent modules of this module
    ExternalModuleDependencies = @('ActiveDirectory')
```

It looks like the dependency needs to be in an array format. Why it doesn't just generate automatically like that is beyond me. I was able to publish my module after this!